# Vue 3: How to combine multiple ref

Tags: vuejs3

How to combine multiple ref value in one:

```
        const variable1 = ref(false);
        const variable2 = ref('');
        const variable3 = ref(false);
        const variable4 = ref(false);           
        const variable5 = ref(false);
        const variable6 = ref(false);
```

Comment: Can't you create an object here? It's pretty hard to understand where are you coming from and what you want to achieve at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an object instead:

```js
// Creation
const myValues = ref({
  someVar: true,
  otherValue: false
})

// In code somewhere
myValues.value.someVar = false
```

Instead you could also use `reactive`. Replacing the object isn't possibel then though.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked `reactive` (ref. https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#declaring-reactive-state)?

```js
const myReactiveVar = reactive({
       variable1 : false,
       variable2 : '',
       variable3 : false,
       variable4 : false,           
       variable5 : false,
       variable6 : false,
});
```

changing any field trigger your watchers or computed values